# Duplicated WordPress plugin activation issues. How to activate both plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, duplicates, copy

I have duplicated a WordPress plugin. Both plugins are working as I need, but the problem is that I can only activate one plugin at a time.

If one plugin is activated then the other plugin activation is not working without giving an error message. (I already have tried **WP_DEBUG** etc)

The plugin is a custom plugin so can't share the URL or name of the plugin.

Comment: Hi @Amir, you need to change the function names and classes name for second plugin.

Comment: @YogeshGarg I have already done these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to download the whole plugin and study the core functionality, change the plugin name to a new one, change all the variables used inside it to a new one.
Or you can check this link, there are some plugins
http://wpkicker.com/duplicate-plugins-wordpress/

Comment: I already have done this, the variables and plugin name is changed, even the plugin function names are also changed. The link you shared is not related to my question.

Comment: The link contains plugins that can duplicate site, pages, and what note other than plugins.